# Operation of push_back on an element of Vector (C++)

Tags: c++, vector, stl, push-back

I am a Python programmer trying to develop C++ proficiency. I have a silly question about vectors.

Suppose I have a vector like this

```
vector<int> adj;
```

Assume it contains some values. What does this operation do ?

```
adj[v].push_back(w)
```

Does it create vector of vectors ? How is it different from having a,

```
vector<vector<int>> adj
```

to begin with ?

Edit::
Associated code is a simple BFS on graph which compiles and runs perfectly.

```
class Graph 
{ 
    int V;  
    vector<int> *adj;    
public: 
    Graph(int V); 
    void addEdge(int v, int w);   
    void BFS(int s);   
}; 

Graph::Graph(int V) 
{ 
    this->V = V; 
    adj = new vector<int>[V]; 
} 

void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w) 
{ 
    adj[v].push_back(w); // Add w to v’s list. 
}
```

The BFS function is in [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/breadth-first-search-or-bfs-for-a-graph/)

Comment: That shouldn't even compile.

Comment: `adj[v]` returns an `int` (assuming `v < adj.size()`), but `int` in C++ is not a struct or a class so it cannot call any field or method with a dot... so it won't compile as mentioned in comment above.

Comment: In the code sample, `adj` is a pointer to a `list`. Doing `adj[v]` is telling the compiler `adj` actually points to an array and I want the `v`th list in that array, then add `w` to that list. Of course, here, you only have 1 list, so any value of `v` other than 0 is an error. However, this code sample is not representative of the question you ask. You would be asking about `vector<int> * adj;` and not `vector<int> adj;`.

Comment: Please dont edit questions in a way that invalidates existing answers. Instead make a new question that's different. And next time, be sure to make a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that the question you ask is the same as the question you thought you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the provided class definition there is no vector.

```
class Graph 
{ 
    int V;  
    list<int> *adj;    
public: 
    Graph(int V); 
    void addEdge(int v, int w);   
    void BFS(int s);   
};
```

There is declared a data member that has the type pointer to `std::list<int>`.

In the constructor of the class

```
Graph::Graph(int V) 
{ 
    this->V = V; 
    adj = new list<int>[V]; 
}
```

there is allocated dynamically an array of objects of the type `std::list<int>` and the address of the first element of the array is assigned to the data member `adj`.

Thus in this statement

```
adj[v].push_back(w);
```

there is selected the element of the array with the index `v`, `adj[v]`,  that represents an object of the type `std::list<int>` and to this list is appended the object `w` using the member function `push_back` of the class template `std::list`.

As for vectors then you indeed can declare a vector of vectors like

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v;
```

To use the subscript operator you have to create a required number of elements of the vector.

You can do it for example when the vector is declared.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v( 10 );
```

This declaration declares a vector of vectors with 10 elements. Now you may use the subscript operator to add sub-vectors to the vector using the member function `push_back`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v( 10 );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ )
    {
        int value = 0;
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < i + 1; j++ )
        {
            v[i]. push_back( value++ );
        }
    }

    for ( const auto &sub_vec : v )
    {
        for ( const auto &item : sub_vec )
        {
            std::cout << item << ' ';
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 
0 1 
0 1 2 
0 1 2 3 
0 1 2 3 4 
0 1 2 3 4 5 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I fixed my question and replaced list with vector. You explanation was perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `vector<int> adj`:

`adj[v].push_back(w)` will call the `operator[]` on adj, which will return an `int &` (assuming `v` is some scalar).  Then it will try to call `push_back` on an `int &` which will fail to compile.

Assuming `vector<vector<int>> adj`:

`adj[v].push_back(w)` will call the `operator[]` on adj, which will return an `vector<int> &` (assuming `v` is some scalar).  Then it will call `push_back` on that `vector<int> &`, appending the value `w` to that particular vector.

Answer (score 2):

In the code that you present, `adj` is created as a `new list<int>[V]`. Which is not exactly what you ask about (i.e. it is not a vector, neither a list, it is a ***dynamically allocated array of lists***).

Then:

```
adj[v].push_back(w)
```

Means: get the `v` element in the array of lists (as v == index of the element to retrieve), it would be a list, then `push_back` into this list `w`.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted tries to call `push_back` on a element of a `vector` of `int`s. That makes *no* sense since a `int` is not an object with a `push_back` member function. That code won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

You have a 1-dimensional array. You can only add 1 element per index. What you are implying by `adj[v].push_back(w)` is that you want to push element w at index v which is not possible since you declared the vector as

`vector<int> adj;`

To implement 2-d vector you need to define it as -

```
vector<vector<int> >adj;
```

On this your operation `adj[v].push_back(w)` would work if v is a valid index.